# The Existence and Uniqueness of a diffusive system

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Some theory for study the following system of pde...

$u_t = f(u,v) + d_1(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$

$v_t = g(u,v) + d_2(v_{xx} + v_{yy})$

where $u=u(x,y,t)$, $v = v(x,y,t)$, such that $(x,y,t)\in\mathbb{R}_{+,0}^{3}$ and $f,g\in C^0(\mathbb{R}_{+,0}^{2}) $

with different boundary conditions. (TThe system is a model for the predator-prey interaction)

Thanks friends!

Comment: Without an initial condition the systems does not have a unique solution for sure, since we can take infinitely many different initial conditions.

Comment: But, what theory is used?